# Multiple Users for the same Remote Desktop in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, ip, remote-access, credentials

I want to set different user id and passwords for different users of the remote desktop in windows 7.

I'm having the ip for example 192.168.0.1 for remote login.
I want to assign different user id and password to my friend with limited access.
Help me out for the same.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following steps.
1. Log on your computer locally **as administrator**
2. Open **Computer Management**
3. Find **Local users and Groups**
4. Right-click the users and click **New users**
5. Just Create two users and set the different password for them
6. Then right-click the **Groups**
7. Find the group **Remote Desktop Users**
8. Double-click the group and add the two users you create in it

Now your friends can remote access to your PC by the two users you set on their own PC.